# Xamarin.Forms MediaElement in 4.6.0847, files, and UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, mediaelement

I'm using the new experimental MediaElement in Xamarin Forms and want to play files from the Video library on UWP. Using a file picker, I get an absolute path, create a FileMediaSource and set the MediaElement.Source. When I try to play an MP4 file, MediaElement.MediaFailed is called and no video plays. Nothing interesting in the event args.

I have set the experimental flag, and this works fine when compiled on Android. It also works on UWP if I create a MediaSource using a Uri. Could this be an issue with file access due to sandboxing on UWP? Any ideas? TIA.

Comment: You can't just use absolute path. User have to give you access to file (using file or folder picker).

Comment: I'm using jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows, which should call `StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(file);`. Shouldn't this handle the access issue? Or should it return a non-absolute path? Thanks.

Comment: If the user picked up file first, this should solve the issue. How does that plugin retrieve the file?Bcs adding to futureAccessList generates token which should be used to retrieve file later..

Comment: Xamarin's FileMediaSource only takes a URI or file path. It doesn't take a stream. Placing the video in the app's LocalFolder works fine on UWP, so it's definitely a file access problem.